# Where did this copy of my home directory come from?

Tags: directory-structure, home

I was working on a project to control my digital camera using Ubuntu and gphoto2.  At one point I noticed a new "~" directory in my project folder, /home/greg/project/~.  When I enter this new "~" directory, it takes me backwards to my home directory /home/greg/ (as you might expect).

I don't know exactly how this happened, but my suspicion is that when I ran gphoto2 on the command line and specified an output file, I typed "~/filename.jpg" expecting the file would show up in my home directory, but instead bash put a new "~" directory in the working directory.  I'm wasn't aware something like that could be done (if that's what happened).

More important than how it got there is how I should get rid of it.  I can't remove the directory, because as far as I can tell it *is* my home directory.  It doesn't appear to be a sym-link, (at least not according to ls -l), but I'm not sure what that would even really mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote it to protect it from shell expansion.

```
ls ~    # list your home directory
ls "~"  # list the directory named ~
ls \~   # list the directory named ~
```

Same thing with `rm`, `rmdir`, etc. The shell changes `~` to `/home/greg` before passing it to the commands, unless you quote or escape it. You can see this with `echo`:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ echo ~
/home/anthony
anthony@Zia:~$ echo \~
~
```

You'll want to be careful, because `rm -Rf ~` would be a disaster. I suggest if at all in doubt, first rename it (`mv -i \~ newname`) then you can examine `newname` to make sure you want to delete it, and then delete it.

Comment: Also: `ls ./~  # list the directory named ~`

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to explain it, thanks!